# Deploying OSX App as an available device (camera)

Tags: macos, camera, device-driver

I have an existing OSX app (Xcode 7, swift) that collects real time data (both textual and photos) from various local and internet (Json) sources to present in a user window.

I want to present the same data stream as an output stream that will appear as if it were just an OSX add-on camera (so that it can be selected as a camera source in other OSX programs).

Having trouble finding any framework documentation or examples for an app to act as a camera. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you ever found some more resources?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this project? https://github.com/rsodre/ofxFakam It seems the way to add a video recording source to OSX is to create and install a quicktime component. Unfortunately I don't know much more than that. On the plus side, it all happens in user space!